# Connect to Interactive Brokers TWS using Python API from another network

Tags: python, python-3.x, stock, interactive-brokers

I'm trying to connect to my TWS application (on my home network) from another network, but my TWS application isn't receiving any connections.

I made sure that I enabled "ActiveX and Socket Clients", set a Master API Client ID, used the correct port and even added my public ip address as a "Trusted IP", but I get no popup to accept a connection.

Here is my code:

```py
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('PUBLIC_IPV4_ADDRESS', 7497, MASTER_API_CLIENT_ID)
```

I get the following error:

```py
ERROR -1 502 Couldn't connect to TWS. Confirm that "Enable ActiveX and Socket EClients" 
is enabled and connection port is the same as "Socket Port" on the 
TWS "Edit->Global Configuration...->API->Settings" menu. Live Trading ports: 
TWS: 7496; IB Gateway: 4001. Simulated Trading ports for new installations 
of version 954.1 or newer:  TWS: 7497; IB Gateway: 4002
ERROR 1 504 Not connected
```

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question properly.  If it's from a different network you'll have to configure your router and firewall as well.  https://groups.io/g/twsapi/message/37480?p=,,,20,0,0,0::Created,,trusted+router,20,2,0,5028259

Comment: @brian Tried that, but it didn't work. I'll just get a local server and run it that way.